# firebase_functions/invalid-argument INVALID ARGUMENT after upgrade to flutter 3

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cloud

i have upgraded my flutter app to flutter 3 and updated all packages.
when im trying to run app all my cloud functions call are returning same error

FirebaseFunctionsException ([firebase_functions/invalid-argument] INVALID ARGUMENT

```html
 


  final HttpsCallable getContentImages =
      FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getContentImages');

  Future<HttpsCallableResult> fetchActiviesData() async {
    return getContentImages.call(<String, dynamic>{});
  }

calling > fetchActiviesData()
```

```html
 HttpsCallable callable =
        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getFamilyActivities');
    final results = await callable();
    List fruit = results.data['data'][
        'activities']; //
```

both are returning  same error any idea why